# el navegador no me reconoce los modulos de javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con los modulos de Javascript, segùn la documentaciòn de Mozilla ya hay soporte para los navegadores , pero aùn asì me sale este error, que le adjunto aquì el codigo que es secillo y el error, claro intente tambien poniendo la etiqueta script con su type=module  y Sin embargo todavia  me sale el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dos cosas: #1 las reglas del sitio especifican que aquello que es codigo debe ir como codigo (texto formateado) en la pregunta, #2 ese error lo obtienes porque intentas abrir directamente desde la computadora el archivo. para poder probar los modulos de `ES6` debes usar un servidor `HTTP` o `HTTPS` que corra por ti ese archivo, existen servidores locales como `xampp` los cuales te permiten dicha funcionalidad, asi con este podras acceder a `localhost` que te permitira usar modulos de `ES6`.

Comment: Aunque si tienes pereza de instalar xampp o quieres una prueba rapida y ligera te recomiendo entonces instalar en su lugar `nodejs`, este te vendra con ciertas herramientas como `npm` que te permiten instalar paquetes atravez de nombres, por lo que la otra opcion es instalar el modulo `http-server` de `nodejs` y usarlo para correr tu archivo, `sudo npm install -g http-server`.

Comment: Por cierto, tal vez ya lo sabes, pero por si acaso, deberias consultar sobre el objeto `Math` en javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math

Comment: ok muchas gracias, por tu comentario

Comment: Intentalo y si te funciona me dices yo planteo una respuesta para que puedas darla como aceptada si te ayudo, si no no te olvides de actualizar la pregunta con los nuevos errores, asi podremos ayudarte.

Comment: ok y disculpa la molestia no me sabia que existia esa regla en este sitio soy nuevo

Comment: era eso instale el paquete http-server de node.js, ya me funciona graciass